# Conditionally lock resources

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have a **consumer** class that is a **Singleton**. Is it possible in any way to ***conditionally*** lock resources. Currently the external resources is **"globally"** locked with the AsyncEx (https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) framework. But I would prefer to lock it based on the **Key** in the input message so messages with different Keys **should not** lock the resource.

```
public class Consumer
{
    private readonly AsyncLock _mutex = new AsyncLock();

    protected async Task Process(Message msg)
    {
       **UNBLOCKED CODE**

       using (await _mutex.LockAsync())
       {
          await GetData(msg.Key);
       }

       **UNBLOCKED CODE**
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What type is `Key`? If it's not a string, it could work with a `lock` statement.

Comment: Yes, that's a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having just one AsyncLock, create a dictionary full of them. The message key is the key to the AsyncLock in the dictionary. As long as there is just one message with a given key processing at a time, there won't be any blocking. I am further assuming that your message key is a string.

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, AsyncLock> _mutexes = new Dictionary<string, AsyncLock>();

private AsyncLock GetMutex(string key)
{
    lock (_mutexes)
    {
        AsyncLock mutex;
        if (!_mutexes.TryGetValue(key, out mutex))
        {
            // no mutex yet, create a new one
            mutex = new AsyncLock();
            _mutexes.Add(key, mutex);
        }
        return mutex;
    }
}

....
protected async Task Process(Message msg)
{
    using (await GetMutex(msg.Key).LockAsync())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

<strike>Please note that in all likelihood the GetMutex method can be further optimized to avoid a lock operation if the mutex for a key already exists, e.g. by first checking with ContainsKey, if not then lock and add. But I'm not sure if that optimization is 100% threadsafe so I did not include it here.</strike>

Inspired by Jason's ConcurrentDictionary comments I decided to provide the code for the ConcurrentDictionary version of GetMutex. I do not recommend to attempt what I crossed out above about optimizing access to a non-threadsafe dictionary.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, AsyncLock> _mutexes = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AsyncLock>();

private AsyncLock GetMutexes(string key)
{
    return _mutexes.GetOrAdd(key, s => { return new AsyncLock(); });
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of ConcurrentDictionary and just looked up its usage. From what I can tell, you'll need to do two operations with the ConcurrentDictionary. First a TryGetValue, and if that fails a GetOrAdd (since you don't want to create an AsyncLock on every lookup if you only called GetOrAdd).

Comment: You don't want to do any operations on a regular `Dictionary` without locking. Consider the case where one thread takes the lock and adds an item to the dictionary in the middle of another thread's attempt to find a key.

Comment: And RE: `ConcurrentDictionary`, there is an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `GetOrAdd` that takes a delegate for creation of a new `TValue` instance. Using that overload would avoid the need to create a new `AsyncLock` on every call. I believe the primary use case for the `GetOrAdd(TKey, TValue)` overload is when TValue is a value type.

Comment: Works perfect with ConcurrentDictionary. Maybe should I change the ConcurrentDictionary to ConcurrentDictionary<string,Lazy<AsyncLock>> ?

Comment: I don't think that makes sense. ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd will not create new AsyncLocks on every access. The anonymous method inside GetOrAdd only gets executed when a given key cannot be found. At that point a new AsyncLock is created and moments later it will be used in the using block anyway. No point in deferring the creation for 1 microsecond.